# Make Mac OS X mouse acceleration more Windows-like

Tags: macos, mouse

The mouse acceleration on Mac OS X is driving me nuts. It may work for touchpads but nothing beats the [Windows' acceleration curves](http://www.microsoft.com/whdc/archive/pointer-bal.mspx). Is there a way to modify the behaviour on OS X? I tried getting a Microsoft mouse driver for OS X but it didn't work since my mouse is not from Microsoft.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Take a look at [Mouse Acceleration Preference Pane](http://triq.net/software/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x).

Comment: Nice to see a free Mac app. Also tried steermouse but didn't find an ideal program for this to be honest. I think Apple really should copy the MS Windows acceleration algorithm.

Comment: Although I'm a new Mac user, I've read that it was more like Windows in OS 9 and earlier. For some reason they thought it would be helpful to have this bizarre scheme in OS X. Still, we are talking about a company that thinks the Mighty Mouse is a good idea - even most Mac fanatics hate that!

Comment: This now works with Mac OSX 10.6 Snow Leopard.

Comment: Yes, it works on Snow Leapard - without acceleration, defeating the purpose of the program. -1 for wasting my time.

Comment: Had the same problem especially when gaming Quake Live. Installed this app, killed the acceleration.. Winning!

Comment: Yes, without acceleration I found this worthless. Note that is Apple's fault for removing the API rather than the developers. I switched to mousefix (see my other answer).

Comment: Anyone have the exact settings?  maybe its best to use based on personal preference.  I've set mine to 2.6x, which is arbitrary, but I'm liking it a lot more than without the this prefPane.  I will also note, I am using a 1080p monitor, i think there are others commenting on screen size makes a difference.

Comment: I know this is an old post. But this App doesn't work anymore in Big Sur

Answer (score 20):

To turn off mouse acceleration entirely, run the following in the terminal:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1
```

This made it feel pretty Windows-y to me. Love Apple's trackpads, but the mouse settings are full of fail.

To turn mouse acceleration back on, change anything in the mouse preference pane, or run the command again with 1 instead of -1.

Comment: I think this is ok if you only have a one, smaller display. With multiple big displays you really need some sort of acceleration.

Comment: oh god, thank you lord! I wasn't even sure I needed it but my dear God, this is a huge difference.

Comment: Oh, thank you very much!!! That weird acceleration was driving me crazy...

Comment: I liked `defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling 9` the best for the Magic Mouse 2

Answer (score 19):

Another new option is [SmoothMouse](http://smoothmouse.com/). Its work on Mountain Lion and supports the Magic Mouse. Some folks are quite happy with it ([discussion](http://smoothmouse.net/forum/topic/78-wow-i-can-use-a-mouse-on-os-x/)). I'm personally still deciding (but already think its better than standard OSX).

Comment: Just installed it, and having bought a few other options, I think I finally found my solution in this free application. Its Windows mouse curve emulation works great, and after firing up Quake3 arena on mac, I made some jumps I was not able to make until now.

One additional note is that it apparently also corrects the mouse lag in OS X... and all this as of OS X 10.8

Comment: Just confirming that it is works fine in10.10

Comment: Very good utility - unfortunately conflicts with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) which is more important (for me) - it would be possible for the authors to fix that issue though

Comment: On mac when you move the mouse slower, the speed is not constant, it bugs me a lot, this one was what I was looking for, thanks!

Comment: I have a [Logitech MX Performance](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/performance-mouse-mx) mouse and tried a few programs including this and [Mouse Acceleration Preference Pane](http://triq.net/software/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x) (from @seb's answer). This program is spot on for replicating how a mouse handles on both a windows and linux (ubuntu 14.04) environment.

Comment: SmoothMouse is now [discontinued from macOS Sierra onward](http://dae.me/blog/2144/on-macos-sierra-support-and-the-future-of-smoothmouse/). Given that Apple fixed mouse lag a year ago, the author recommends using ControllerMate to set a custom acceleration curve. Unfortunately they don't provide a config containing such a curve.

Answer (score 10):

Try [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/help/?show=configaccel).

[image]

Comment: This is the most unusable program I've used in my life. The interface is so bloated (it looks almost like Photoshop), that I never was able to open the acceleration settings. -1 for wasting my time.

Comment: Link does not work any more.

Answer (score 7):

I may sound extreme, but I connect my mouse to a small, quiet, Windows laptop and use [synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) with the mac as a client. This works well for me.

None, and I repeat, none (I've tried all of them) of the available OS X mouse mods out there actually get your mouse to behave like it does on Windows. They just get you a little closer. Furthermore, regardless of the acceleration curve, OS X has a defect that causes many mice to make erratic jumping movements (apparently this is fixed in OSX Lion...) and no available software (except for OSX Lion) addresses it.

Synergy is not a great solution, but it is *a* solution. In particular you should not run it over wifi and instead use as direct of an ethernet connection as possible to reduce the latency. Also a bummer is that sometimes my cursor disappears, and I have to switch apps with cmd+tab in order to restore it.

As much as a perfectionist as Steve Jobs was, the cursor tracking on OS X unfortunately eluded his attention. The only solution is to actually use Windows, hence synergy.

Comment: +1 on the perfectionist note. MS wins this one.

Comment: A very creative approach :).

Answer (score 6):

Try [SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/)

Don't be put off by the slightly naff website, this is the best one I've found available for Lion. You can download a trial - definitely worth a purchase though.

Just set the tracking speed to 0 and set the sensitivity to whatever feels normal for your mouse.

[image]

Comment: I've been using this for some time now, however, it does not emulate Windows mouse curve. `SmoothMouse` (as already mentioned in this thread) does a better job. But this application does have some handy button remapping.

Answer (score 0):

The command line version of [mousefix/iMouseFix](https://github.com/infowolfe/iMouseFix) continues to work for me on 10.8 (also worked on 10.7 and 10.6) with the Apple MagicMouse and MacBook trackpad (some of the other suggested solutions don't work for the MagicMouse).

I can quickly move the mouse between displays, but also do fine work with a setting of 3.5 on 10.8 and 8 on 10.6.

To use download mousefix.tbz2 from http://code.google.com/p/mousefix-10-6/downloads/list. Then run it on the command line:

```
mousefix 8
```

Once you have the right setting, just added it to your ~/.profile as they suggest in the [README](https://github.com/infowolfe/iMouseFix/blob/master/README)

FYI, The binary download is mousefix.tbz2 at http://code.google.com/p/mousefix-10-6/downloads/list.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Mojave and up:**

This appears to be working for me in 10.15.7

Copy files into place

```
/Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft Mouse.prefPane
/Library/Extensions/MicrosoftMouse.kext
```

Add NSAppleEventsUsageDescription key to:

```
<key>NSAppleEventsUsageDescription</key>
<string>Foo</string>
```

To these file:

```
/Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft Mouse.prefPane/Contents/Resources/MicrosoftMouseHelper.app/Contents/Info.plist
/Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft Mouse.prefPane/Contents/Info.plist (not sure this is needed or works)
```

Fix permissions:

```
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft\ Mouse.prefPane
sudo chown -R root:wheel /Library/Extensions/MicrosoftMouse.kext
sudo touch /System/Library/Extensions
```

Add this to startup:

```
/Library/PreferencePanes/Microsoft\ Mouse.prefPane/Contents/Resources/MicrosoftMouseHelper.app
```

Reboot

Load kexts if needed (verify running in System Profiler, Extensions; I did not need to do this):

```
sudo kextload /Library/Extensions/MicrosoftMouse.kext
sudo kextload /Library/Extensions/MicrosoftMouse.kext/Contents/Plugins/MicrosoftMouseUSB.kext
```

Seems the prefpane errors when launched and shows mouse not plugged in but still allows controls to be manipulated and settings appear not to take effect immediately.

See also:

- https://refluxions.wordpress.com/2008/08/18/mac-os-x-mouse-madnessfixed/
- https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/110481/intellipoint-software-on-os-x-mavericks-not-recognizing-intellimouse
- [Make Mac OS X mouse acceleration more Windows-like](https://superuser.com/questions/5150/make-mac-os-x-mouse-acceleration-more-windows-like)

---

If you have a Microsoft Mouse, you can use IntelliPoint acceleration, which is like Windows.

After disabling SIP, you can still install and use Microsoft IntelliPoint v305 on MacOS 10.13.6. You may need to restart after installing the driver, for a total of 3 restarts (1 to disable SIP, 1 to get back into MacOS, 1 after driver is installed).

I find that you also need to activate the Microsoft Mouse preference pane after the computer restarts.

You can do this with an AppleScript, built as a .app, set to run at login:

```
tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    set the current pane to pane id "com.microsoft.microsoftmouse"
    delay 1
    if application "System Preferences" is running then
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    end if
end tell
```

MacOS updates or clearing PRAM may interfere with the driver. You can tell if it's working by verifiying it shows a picture of your mouse instead of a picture of a USB cable being inserted.

If the driver fails to show the image of the mouse, you may have to:

1. Disable SIP
2. Reinstall the driver

Comment: Installer no longer works in Big Sur.

Comment: @vaughan it doesn't work in Catalina either =( USB overdrive seems to do a good job.

Comment: I had installed it before I upgraded and I have found that you just need to copy the kext into the Extensions dir and it works fine.

Comment: @vaughan which kext? From where to where specifically?

Comment: `/sbin/kextload /Library/Extensions/MicrosoftMouse.kext`. You can probably find it in the installer bundle. Otherwise, just install an earlier version of macOS on a VM and take it from there.

Comment: @vaughan Do you have more details? On my Catalina machine, I uninstalled USB overdrive, restarted, copied the kext and pref pane, installed each, chowned root:wheel each, sudo kextloaded the kext USB plugin kext within, but the pref pane still reports "The Microsoft Mouse extension is not installed properly...". System Profiler shows the extensions are loaded the same as my High Sierra machine that has the working driver. It shows the same version, 8.2.

Comment: The pref pane will never work, but the driver will work. I think it’s because the pref pane is missing a permission plist config and needs to be code signed if you change it.

Comment: @vaughan does that mean I would need to make my adjustments on an old machine and transfer the preference plist over or something? The default settings dont move the mouse like windows

Comment: You might also need the `MicrosoftMouseHelper` running. I would copy every file that installs on High Sierra across. I also had to unplug mouse.

Comment: @vaughan from your comments and another post I was able to get it working, thank you! I updated my answer with all the details