# Disabling mouse acceleration in Mac OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, mouse

I've been looking for a solution to the unusable mouse problem in Mac OS X for ages. I've tried a gazillion programs and fiddled with every setting there is or there can be added. So far, I haven't found a way to get linear mouse response in Mac OS X.

At this point I'm seriously considering installing another operating system.

But before I do that, or go hacking around OS binaries, maybe someone here has a solution?

I want **linear** mouse response. I want high sensitivity. I like my touchpad acceleration and would like to keep it if possible. Any ideas?

P.S. I've been at this for a long time, I'll probably have already tried the most popular answers.

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.5 on a MacBook Pro. I don't use a particular brand of mouse.

I'm not looking for any commercial solutions.

I've tried:

- [Mouse Acceleration Preferences Pane](http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x), the Snow Leopard version of which can get me close to a linear response, but at the cost of tracking speed (sensitivity).
- Answers on this question: [Make Mac OS X mouse acceleration more Windows-like](https://superuser.com/questions/5150/make-mac-os-x-mouse-acceleration-more-windows-like)
- About every code snippet I found via Google.

From what I've gathered so far, the only method to kill the acceleration curve seems to be to set the mouse scaling to a negative value (for which there are apparently two methods.) Unfortunately, this also kills the tracking speed. Before 10.4, there was a function to which you could pass your own acceleration curve which solved everything.

---

By the way, here is the Linux counterpart to this question: [Disabling mouse acceleration in X.Org (Linux)](https://superuser.com/questions/259216/disabling-mouse-acceleration-in-x-org-linux)

...and here's the programmatical variant, as I'll be trying to roll my own solution: [Disabling mouse acceleration in Mac OS X @ SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5782884/disabling-mouse-acceleration-in-mac-os-x)

Comment: Sorry Daniel, I've tried so many things I cannot remember/re-find them all. I do appreciate your help, though, and your "redundant" suggestions might help others, so don't hold back on my account.

Comment: [This](http://triq.net/articles/mouse-curve-app-mac-os-x) was posted in August: A rather desperate solution hacking the mouse driver. I'm don't expect alternatives have popped up in the short time since then.

Comment: @Daniel Beck: Excellent, thanks. Unfortunately, there's been no release yet. It's still nice to know it's possible.

Comment: @aib If you're up for writing your own, it's likely that the [mouse curve app](http://triq.net/articles/mouse-curve-app-mac-os-x) is just tweaking the acceleration settings (`HIDPointerAccelerationSettings`, `HIDPointerAccelerationTable`, `HIDPointerAccelerationType`, etc.) in the IORegistry of the `IOHIDPointing` object associated with the mouse. `IOHIDFamily` is open source, so you can figure out how the driver interprets those settings.

Comment: I've only done superficial research, but it seems that the user-space API for tweaking the curve is deprecated in the latest version of the OS; now there're only two floating-point values to set, as available in the latest version of that app. I'm still up for writing my own, but I think I'll need lower-level code than a user app.

Comment: @aib Maybe you can contact the Mouse Curve author regarding being a willing beta tester? Though from the comments on that page it doesn't seem like he has a shortage...

Comment: If you're here you're probably frustrated, so here's some trivia to lighten your mood: Did you know that the first time I tried to use the mouse on a Mac it took me **more than 10 seconds** to click a large 32x32 Firefox button (only ~3 of which I spent banging my head on the desk)? The muridae challenged Quake 3 railgunner that I am, I kept under- and overshooting it.

Comment: Have you seen this article: http://www.l337tech.com/tips-and-tricks/fix-mac-mouse-acceleration-and-scrolling-speed/ If you're open to installing third-party drivers for your mouse, it seems like this presents a workable solution. I personally prefer the mouse tracking in OS X and find Windows annoying, so I feel a little too unloved to post an actual answer here. ;-)

Comment: @Cody Gray: I'd really prefer not to use a 3rd party mouse driver (especially since I'm on a laptop and can plug in all kinds of different makes of mice) but at this rate it looks like I'm going to have to write my own.

Comment: @Cody Gray I tried that article and it doesn't work. The mouse still has acceleration. It's incredible how so much ppl say that Macs are the best, yet Cupertino cannot get something so simple straight.

Comment: @amateur: Mouse acceleration curves are entirely a matter of personal preference. It's not a matter of Apple being unable to "get it straight". You could say the same thing about Microsoft being unable to get font smoothing right when OS X has had this for years. But that again is a matter of personal preference, whether or not one chooses to respect the pixel grid. Inflammatory comments like that one never helped anyone. It's incredible how you can lambaste the work of others, you cannot even follow instructions in a simple article.

Comment: Funny, it literally *is* a matter of getting things straight. (In this case, it would be the pointer curve.) I'm not going to discuss things further, because I've already conceded the point that linear response is the only logical, universal choice in favor of calling it all "personal preference." Still, it amazes me how some people have no standards about a device they use for hours on end to interact with a device they do all their work on.

Comment: @Cody Gray They had things straight on the last release of the Mac OS X... but they decided to fix something that wasn't broken, and remove an API function that allowed you to modify the mouse curve to your personal preferences. Now it's not a matter of personal preferences, it's a matter of only using Cupertino's preferences. And not allowing personal preferences for something as simple as a mouse setting is horribly wrong for a computer that costs $1.3K+ dollars, and is marketed as "superior" to Windows.

Comment: @aib: Of course, I wasn't talking to you. My last comment was addressed to a different user, not sure how you missed that. Also, your arrogance is *astounding*. It's definitely a personal preference. I, for example, *strongly* prefer the acceleration curve in Mac OS X. And it's not an issue of Stockholm syndrome. I'm a Windows developer, and I spend 10-12 hours a day using Windows. I still don't like it. But that's not the point; you asked a valid question, and I have no complaints about that. I take issue with claiming that Apple is incompetent because they do something you dislike.

Comment: @amateur: It is superior to Windows. The mouse acceleration curve is one of those things that makes it superior. Obviously that superiority is lost on you. Remember that there **is** an alternative: you could just use Windows, like tons of other people. Macs even run Windows now. Stop complaining.

Comment: @Cody Gray "superiority lost on me"? No one has insulted you here.

Comment: Personal preferences are just that: _personal_. If somebody does or doesn't like mouse acceleration, that's their prerogative. The point of Super User is to get answers to questions about computers, and this is a perfectly valid question. Please stop bickering about whose OS is "superior", or the irrelevant comments will be deleted.

Answer (score 9):

Use your manufacturer's mouse driver, if available

Alternatives are the general, commercial, all-purpose mouse utilities/drivers [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) or [Steermouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/), or use [Mouse Acceleration Preference Pane](http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x).

Comment: I have to use the newer version of MAPP, which doesn't have curve editing. Right now the closest I can get to a linear response is at -0.4x acceleration, but the sensitivity is terrible. I will not use commercial software simply because **I find it ridiculous to buy software in order be able to use a mouse**. I would rather spend a couple of hours to write one myself, though I guess that's a topic for SO.

Comment: @aib You don't **have to buy software to use a mouse**, you just want to alter the way the mouse works.

Comment: OK, I'll agree that it's a point-of-view-issue. To me (and I, apparently, might be the only person on the planet with this point of view) it **is** the difference between "working" and "not working". I've unplugged my mouse and stopped using anything on Mac that can't be controlled via the touchpad or a graphic tablet.

Comment: @aib +2 for not being the only person in the planet that is frustrated. Right now I bought a new Logitech laser mouse and it's sitting right next to the computer as a decoration device. Feeling like going back to Best Buy and getting my money back.

Answer (score 6):

Short answer, write on a Terminal:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.trackpad.scaling -1
```

That should do it for both mouse and trackpad. If you want to restore the default values, type:

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling
```

Big-time answer, check out [Mouse Curves Acceleration Preference Pane](http://ttp://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x) (free [download](http://triq.net/articles/mouse-acceleration-download)).
Open your Preferences Panel > Mouse Acceleration and set the Mouse value to 0.0x

That should do it but if you want more control you can also check the App at the same page that gives you full control on these and other mouse settings.

Comment: Does not work for Snow Leopard because Jobs decided to drop an API function which is a dependency of that program. It only works for Mac users with old versions of the OS.

Comment: Good news! It works again in 10.8

Comment: works in el capitan 10.11.1 too!

Great answer, for providing how to restore as well.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem because I wanted to try League of Legends, an RTS-like online game - mouse acceleration can be a pain when you want precision combined with swift movement of your hand.

I found [ControllerMate](http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/), which worked like a charm after some tweaks and tests:

> ControllerMate is a controller programming tool that allows you to
>   customize the behavior of your HID devices — keyboards, keypads, mice,
>   trackballs, joysticks, gamepads, throttles, among others.
>   ControllerMate’s philosophy is to be as flexible as possible, to
>   provide a set of basic programming tools, and to allow the user to
>   combine those tools in an endless variety of ways.

[image]

Comment: I was never able to get USB Overdrive, MouseZoom, or anything else to produce a windows like cursor ballistic, but ControllerMate did the job. It's a bit of a hack and annoying, but at least it works. Since then I've moved to just using a mouse with OSX driver support.

Comment: I downloaded controllermate and it is highly unusable, plus you have to dole out cash for it. 15 minutes of my life that I'm never going to recover.

Answer (score 4):

See this thread : [Tired of Mac OS X's mouse acceleration?](http://forums3.armagetronad.net/viewtopic.php?t=3364)

Several solutions are discussed, including the source of a 21-lines C program that will turn of scaling, also available as a downloadable attachment. I suggest reading the entire thread first.

Comment: Already read it, but might be something I missed the first time around so I'm gonna read it from the top again, and drop another feedback here.

Comment: Nope, sorry. This is the mouse acceleration preferences pane method, which kills tracking speed along with the acceleration curve.

Comment: @aib +1 for saving me 15 minutes of my life.

Answer (score 4):

Give [MouseZoom](http://benh57.com/mousezoom.html) a try, it worked for me to slow down mouse motion.

Comment: But I want to speed it up! Only without acceleration. By the way, if you want to know what the acceleration is like, try the maximum setting on that program. Tell me it's usable and I'll drop my quest for linear mouse response. That counter-intuitive response curve is exactly what's happening on the lower settings, only less exaggerated.

Answer (score 4):

```
defaults write .GlobalPreferences com.apple.mouse.scaling -1
```

I use steermouse and it allows you to independently set acceleration and tracking speed.  One thing, having manufacturer's driver and steermouse installed messes things up.

Comment: Worked for me in 10.8

Comment: context please. where do we write this, and how do we get to it?

Answer (score 3):

I use this fix from TeamLiquid, dubbed MouseFixer2:

http://www.teamliquid.net/forum/viewmessage.php?topic_id=194668

Answer (score 2):

[SmoothMouse.com](http://smoothmouse.com) seems to be the solution. It is a project to improve mouse and trackpad usability.

It works great on my MacBook Air running OSX Mavericks.

Comment: This is a good utility although it conflicts with [Karabiner](https://pqrs.org/osx/karabiner/) which is a dealbreaker for me

Answer (score 1):

There is a preference pane which can be installed to eliminate acceleration in OS X, available [here](http://ariekanarie.nl/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2010/06/MouseAccelerationPref11c.zip).

It may sound counter-intuitive, but to remove the acceleration, set "Mouse" to -6.0x.

Comment: Seems awfully familiar to the one I posted in my question. Sorry, but it kills mouse sensitivity along with the acceleration curve. It's what I'm using at the moment (or trying to, rather.)

Answer (score 1):

If you also have a PC set up next to your Mac, you can use Synergy+ to share the PC's mouse. This has the added benefit of using the PC's mouse speed and acceleration settings, and if you're on Windows you can disable these from Control Panel.

Note that the Windows machine must be setup as the server, with the Mac as a client.

Answer (score 1):

Give [USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/USBOverdrive/News.html) a try.

Comment: Having used USB Overdrive and the Razer OSX drivers, USB overdrive is the clear winner.

Comment: The user already responded in december (see my answer) that he didn't want to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Because of this issue, I put away a logitech G5.
I solved the problem using a Magic Mouse. Its drivers provide a smooth pointer acceleration I didn't find in any other mouse.

This is not a good solution, but worked for me...

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a Logitech G400 so this might only apply to that family of mice.

Using the Logitech gaming software, turn the DPI sensitivity all the way up (3600) and the polling rate all the way down (125).

Then in OSX mouse system preferences turn the tracking speed down almost all the way.  This not only removed acceleration for me, but also fixed problems where the pointer would freeze or stick at low speeds.

Comment: here it is 2021, and this totally worked for me

Answer (score 1):

As of MacOS 14 Monterey, this is (finally!) a built-in feature!

1. Go to the `Mouse` system setting pane
2. Click `Advanced...` in the bottom right
3. Toggle the `Pointer acceleration` setting

[image: A screenshot of the advanced settings dialogue, showing the pointer acceleration toggle.]

You can also script the same change with `defaults`:

```sh
# When linear, acceleration is off
defaults write NSGlobalDomain com.apple.mouse.linear -bool YES
```

Answer (score 0):

I was going to toss [BetterTouchTool](http://www.boastr.de/) into the ring but I saw your dislike for 3rd party software to make the mouse shape up. I'm adding it here in hope it helps someone else in the future.

Comment: I'm only against commercial solutions: It's ridiculous to have to pay money to be able to use a mouse. I'll give that a try, thanks.

Comment: @aib I find it interesting how you keep saying "ridiculous to have to pay money to be able to use a mouse". Having used Windows since 3.0 and OS X since 10.0 (plus System 7, 8 and 9) and a varieties of Linuxes and BSD, I have yet to find a mouse that requires me to pay something extra… they all work out of the box. Your rant about having to pay is incorrectly expressed. That'd be the same if I complained about XX feature of YY operating system and complaining that it's unusable and that I have to pay for it to be changed.

Comment: @Martín Marconcini: I agree; I am romanticising the subject, but *feature bloat* is one of the things I cannot help feeling strongly about. It's a major usability issue (especially with Mac OS's acceleration curve) and to think that it could've been easily prevented - by *removing* code... Also, to make an easy point: If you've used so many systems, you already know that each one has a different acceleration code, and thus, mouse response. Linear response is the only universal one.

Comment: Oh, and I wasn't really exaggerating: See the 7th comment on this question. How hard should it be to land your pointer on a button?

Comment: @aib I know all the OSses use different algorithms and therefore the response is not the same, but I don't find it particularly hard to switch from one to the other; if anything I find Windows a little bit awkward to move. What I do believe is that one gets used after days of practice. Muscle memory is hard to beat, but not impossible. In any case, I really don't use the mouse that much these days. Launchbar and shortcuts are my mouse ;)

Answer (score 0):

I hear there's a nice little App called [Decelerator](http://www.bulldozersoftware.com/x/decelerator) might just do the trick! ;-)

(Shameless plug, I wrote it. :D)

Comment: Does it let you adjust the pointer speed? Without acceleration, that is.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking for Big Sur:

[CursorSense](https://plentycom.jp/en/cursorsense/) is capable of this, however it is paid software.

SteelSeries ExactMouse is also capable of this, however only for USB mice - not for touchpads.

Instead I found https://github.com/docwhat/killmouseaccel which is a free solution that will remove acceleration on a mouse or touchpad, while maintaining the ability to adjust sensitivity.

Launching it on startup is covered well here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372744

Answer (score 0):

I have become accustomed to the Microsoft IntelliMouse acceleration curve. The driver is only compiled for Intel so doesn't work on new MacBooks.

I am in the process of writing a DriverKit driver for the mouse.

macOS pointer acceleration is performed [here in IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/3f62fef86e2938e0f362e70eede0a914222c3e27/IOHIDEventSystemPlugIns/IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp#L451). It is implemented as a [CFPlugin](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFPlugIns/index.html), and *roughly* implements the [`IOHIDServiceFilter.h`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/6fb6fe70a90016f2e566a84e5876df3da953b4f2/HID/HIDServiceFilter.h) interface. The instantiation point of this "filter" is not open-source AFAICT.

```
$ sudo log stream --level debug --predicate 'subsystem == "com.apple.iohid"'

WindowServer: (IOKit) [com.apple.iohid:default] Add filter:IOHIDServiceFilter uuid:25268D26-BB27-4522-AEBC-02B6A6B920AC name:com.apple.iokit.hid.IOHIDPointerScrollFilter  for service:0x1000df3e6
```

An [`IOHIDPointerAccelerator`](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/3f62fef86e2938e0f362e70eede0a914222c3e27/IOHIDEventSystemPlugIns/IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp#L620) is created which takes an `algorithm` as input. The `algorithm` can be created with an `IOHIDTableAcceleration` (which is how IntelliPoint encoded their accel curve), or with `IOHIDParametricAcceleration`. The parametric way seems like an improvement on the table, allowing for a smoother acceleration curve, rather than defining a jagged curve based on a few xy coords.

The IntelliMouse curve was defined in the `Info.plist` as a simple binary protocol under the key `HIDPointerAccelerationTable`. You can see a plot of the curve [here](https://chart-studio.plotly.com/%7Evjpr/4/hidpointeraccelerationtable-intellimouse-explorer-30/#/).

IntelliMouse used to use `IOHIPointing` but this is now deprecated.

Normally, you can set properties for HID devices like so (this is matching my IntelliMouse):

```
hidutil property --matching '{"ProductID":0x47}' --set '{"HIDPointerAcceleration":0}'
```

This is how you would disable acceleration. However, it will not report when it fails to set a property, and these settings don't seem to update the System Preferences UI.

You can see [here](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/3f62fef86e2938e0f362e70eede0a914222c3e27/IOHIDEventSystemPlugIns/IOHIDPointerScrollFilter.cpp#L375) where `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter` will run its acceleration setup on response to a property change. However, it seems there is a whitelist of properties that are allowed to be set, and `HIDPointerAccelerationTable` is not one of them. If you could do this, then we would have full control over pointer acceleration from a single CLI command. Alas, I could not find a way.

*The whitelist might be defined in [IOHIDSystem::createParameters](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/main/IOHIDSystem/IOHIDSystem.cpp#L3412)*

*This [line](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/IOHIDFamily/blob/6fb6fe70a90016f2e566a84e5876df3da953b4f2/HIDServiceFilterExample/HIDServiceFilterExample.m#L55)* in the `HIDServiceFilterExample.m` gives me some hope, but I don't think `HIDServiceFilterExample` is the same base that is being used by the `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter`.

This leaves me with the only option to write a driver and copy over the `IOHIDPointerScrollFilter` code. But DriverKit doesn't allow CoreFoundation or stdlib so it's taking some time.

Related: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/698409

Answer (score -4):

Magic Mouse. Inertial Scrolling set to off. You'll be back to Windows 3.0 but I have no idea why you would want to be.