# my mouse appears to be weird on Macbook Pro

Tags: laptop, mouse, macbook-pro, touchpad

Does anyone have some problems using their mouse on Macbook Pro. My mouse works perfectly fine on my Windows laptop but it appears weird on my Macbook Pro. I think maybe the inertia thing is on or something, I've adjusted everything I can on system preferences -> mouse but still my mouse is very hard to control. (it's jerky and i can't have precise control over where the mouse is moving)

Comment: Please explain *how* it is weird. Could it be related to [this question](http://superuser.com/questions/218314/disabling-mouse-acceleration-in-mac-os-x)?

Comment: @Daniel Beck i've updated the question

Comment: Have you tried rebooting, using a different USB port?

Comment: @Daniel Beck definitely i've rebooted and tried a different USB port (i'v only got 2 ports)

Comment: @Pacerier What kind of mouse?  It might Mac drivers to work right.

Comment: @Chris_O mine is a Logitech mouse. its a cheap one at $17 SGD but its working perfectly fine on my windows laptop

Comment: @Pacerier go to the [Logitech Download Page](http://www.logitech.com/en-us/support-downloads/downloads/mice) and see if your model supports the Logitech Control Center.  Even some of the cheap ones do.

Comment: @Chris_O i mean what can i do if it supports the Logitech Control Center?

Comment: Download it, install it and use to adjust the mouse settings.

Comment: @Chris_O dang there's no support for mine. mine is M110 http://www.logitech.com/en-us/428/6608?WT.z_sp=Image

Comment: @Pacecerier Yes there is, see the download link in the answer I just posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mouse needs the Mac OSX Logitech Drivers and Logitech Control Center which can be downloaded from the [Logitech support page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkboM.png) for the M110.

http://www.logitech.com/en-us/428/6608?section=downloads&bit=&osid=9

Install the package (might require a reboot) go to System - Preferences

Open the preferences for Logitech under other.

[image]

The settings available for your model will be available to adjust.  The pointer speed is controlled in the general settings.

[image]