# How can I set mouse sensitivity exactly the same in Windows 7 and Mac OS X Lion?

Tags: windows-7, macos, mac, mouse

I have a Microsoft mouse:

[image]

I bought it for gaming in Windows 7. I hate switching the magic mouse and this when restarting my comp, so I decided to stick with it.

One annoying thing with it is sensitivity (Believe me, very, very annoying!). I want to set it in Lion exactly the same as in Windows 7 value. I installed Microsoft intellipoint software for OS X too, but for some reason I could never set it to the same value as in Windows.

[image]

The pointer feels like it lags or or sticks to a point for a moment sometimes, don't know why.

How can I fix this? Is there a value in the registry somewhere and a `.plist` file in Mac OS X I should search for and set to the same value? Or do I need to buy another mouse?

Comment: [Possibly related](http://superuser.com/questions/5150/make-mac-os-x-mouse-acceleration-more-windows-like).

Comment: do you have any idea how could I compare the windows value with os x value ?

Comment: Good luck with this one. It's hard enough to get the mouse to behave from version to version of the same OS. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best solution what I found to this, is [Steer Mouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse/index.html).

The mouse will not behave exactly as in windows. But will do a better job.

I've tested it with a Microsoft 5000 and a Razer Lachesis.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to calibrate and reproduce by yourself your sensitivity configuration using the [Mouse Sensitivity Exporter](http://mousesensexport.sourceforge.net/) tool, it's a crossplatform tool made to calibrate sensitivity reliably. It works on Windows but I'm not sure it would work on MacOSX, but you can try with the Linux package, it's a simple Python script.