# How to modify mouse acceleration curve on Windows to make it more MacOS-like?

Tags: windows-10, macos, mouse

This question is a reverse of [Make Mac OS X mouse acceleration more Windows-like](https://superuser.com/questions/5150/make-mac-os-x-mouse-acceleration-more-windows-like)
.

I used to work on MacOS and feel its mouse acceleration fits me better. Now I tried to get myself used to it on Windows, but after a week of use it's still feeling a little bit weird.

The thing I mainly found uncomfortable is its almost linear acceleration-curve on Windows. **I need to make my mouse sensitive for big monitors, but at the same time don't want to lose its accuracy for tiny movements.** On MacOS I find its builtin curve a best fit so I tried to tweak the curve on Windows but without luck.

Comment: Hmm, I thought you can get this by cranking the pointer speed to high and checking the "Increase pointer precision" box (within `main.cpl`)? Also, to clarify, are you talking about actual mice – not touchpads nor trackpoints?

Comment: Hi @grawity I'm using a magic mouse on windows with almost the highest pointer speed and increase pointer precision checked

Comment: Hoping for this too! Windows needs to play catch up in terms of user experience and Apple has spent the dollars in the right places, mouse movement is one of them.